# How to return the lists of public and obsolete classes for specified .NET assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-reflector

The function should return a list of public but obsolete classes

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetPublicObsoleteClasses(string assemblyName)
        {
            return Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(assemblyName).GetTypes()
                .Where(x => x.IsClass &&
                            x.IsPublic &&
                            Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(x)
                                .Any(y => y is ObsoleteAttribute))
                .Select(x => x.Name);
        }
```

However, it shows that *ReflectionOnly loading is not supported on this platform*.

There is a Unit Test for this method and it is not allowed to change it

```
[Test ]
         
        public void GetPublicObsoleteClassesShouldReturnRightList()
        {
            var expected = "CaseInsensitiveHashCodeProvider, ContractHelper, ExecutionEngineException, "+
                           "FirstMatchCodeGroup, IDispatchImplAttribute, PermissionRequestEvidence, "+
                           "SecurityTreatAsSafeAttribute, SetWin32ContextInIDispatchAttribute, "+
                           "UnionCodeGroup, UnmanagedMarshal";

            var obsoleteMembers = CommonTasks.GetPublicObsoleteClasses("mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0").OrderBy(x=>x);
            var actual = string.Join(", ", obsoleteMembers);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }
```

Comment: *ReflectionOnly loading is not supported on this platform* The obvious question is-- what is your platform? Are you running on Windows?

Comment: @JohnWu yes, Windows 10

Comment: Are you using .NET Core or .NET Framework?

Comment: @JohnWu .NET Core 3.1

Comment: This is a [known gap in .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/1682). Sounds like you're supposed to use [System.Reflection.TypeLoader](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/archive/docs/specs/typeloader.md) instead.

Comment: What should I change? @JohnWu

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already referencing `mscorlib` and it is already loaded to run .NET, one option is to use a `Type` rather than a string to determine what assembly to use.

```
[Test]

public void GetPublicObsoleteClassesShouldReturnRightList()
{
    var expected = "CaseInsensitiveHashCodeProvider, ContractHelper, ExecutionEngineException, " +
                   "FirstMatchCodeGroup, IDispatchImplAttribute, PermissionRequestEvidence, " +
                   "SecurityTreatAsSafeAttribute, SetWin32ContextInIDispatchAttribute, " +
                   "UnionCodeGroup, UnmanagedMarshal";

    var obsoleteMembers = CommonTasks.GetPublicObsoleteClasses(typeof(string) /* mscorlib */).OrderBy(x => x);
    var actual = string.Join(", ", obsoleteMembers);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

public static IEnumerable<string> GetPublicObsoleteClasses(Type typeFromAssembly)
{
    return typeFromAssembly.Assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(x => x.IsClass &&
                    x.IsPublic &&
                    Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(x)
                        .Any(y => y is ObsoleteAttribute))
        .Select(x => x.Name);
}
```

Comment: Is there another way to fix it? Because it is not recommended to change the code in Unit Test

Comment: Maybe. I don't usually make unit tests rely on external dependencies to run because it takes a long time to debug when the external dependency is missing, so I don't have another answer.